# How to Display a preference category as a cardview?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-preferences, android-cardview

I want to display a `PreferenceCategory` as a `CardView`.

In the official Lollipop preference screen they use not directly a `CardView` but there is also a gap between different preferencecategories. How can I do this?

this is my code for the Preferences:

**PrefsFragment (PreferenceFragment)**

```
/**
 * Created by xisberto on 08/11/14.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String category = getArguments().getString("category");
        if (category != null) {
            if (category.equals(getString(R.string.category_general))) {
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_general);
            } else if (category.equals(getString(R.string.category_advanced))) {
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_erscheinungsbild);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Preferences (PreferenceActivity)**

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    private Toolbar mToolBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        prepareLayout();

        buildLegacyPreferences();
    }

    private void prepareLayout() {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View content = root.getChildAt(0);
        LinearLayout toolbarContainer = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_prefs, null);

        root.removeAllViews();
        toolbarContainer.addView(content);
        root.addView(toolbarContainer);

        mToolBar = (Toolbar) toolbarContainer.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolBar.setTitle(getTitle());
        mToolBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void buildLegacyPreferences() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            String action = getIntent().getAction();
            if (action == null) {
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.headers_legacy);
            } else if (action.equals(getString(R.string.category_general))) {
                mToolBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.header_general));
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_general);
            } else if (action.equals(getString(R.string.category_advanced))) {
                mToolBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.header_general));
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_erscheinungsbild);
            }
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        super.onBuildHeaders(target);
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.headers, target);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return fragmentName.equals(PrefsFragment.class.getName());
    }

    public static int getToastDuration(Context context) {
        return (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(PreferenceNames.TOAST_DURATION, "0").equals("0")) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the library I've made: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary . I think that looking at how you can customize there everything, you can achieve this too. I think you should also check this website: http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/settings.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to make another layout/xml file (f.e. preference_category_layout) with this CardView and then

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
            android:layout="@layout/preference_category_layout">
```